# InAppBrowser images aren't caching on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, caching, inappbrowser

I have a phonegap app that only opens a InAppBrowser. When I kill the internetconnection the whole application stays available exepct the images.

When I do the same in Safari, start the app, kill the internet connection, the whole application including images are in the cache.

The question is how can i fix it that the images in the inappbrowser stay in the cache?

Code:

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            app.initialize();
            function onDeviceReady() {
                // Now safe to use the Codova API
                var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://one2ten-system.parseapp.com/v2', '_blank', 'disallowoverscroll=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,zoom=no,hidden=yes');
                ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { ref.show();});

            }
```